# Atomicity with multiple DML's in Snowflake Transactions

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

hi I have a requirement,

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION NAME <name_identifier of the transaction>;

<insert statement> on table ABC

<delete statement> on table ABC

COMMIT;
```

Now I want both the sql should be done or none.
Either statement should not be executed.

HOw should I achieve this. Since I tried.

```
create or replace table test_table(user_id integer,ip_address text,user_agent text,email text);
create or replace table test_table_copy(user_id integer,ip_address text,user_agent text,email text);

begin transaction name test_transaction;

insert into test_table_copy values(100,'1.1.1.1','ua_1','abc1@gmail.com');

insert into test_table values(100,'1.1.1.1','ua_1','abc1@gmail.com');

-- will fail as table name does not exist
delete from test_tablee where user_id = 100;

commit;
```

I am seeing the behaviour as **insert** happening in spite of the fact **delete** statement is failing.

How do I achieve here all done or none done thing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To abort transaction you could set: [TRANSACTION_ABORT_ON_ERROR](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#transaction-abort-on-error) to TRUE.

> TRUE: The non-autocommit transaction is aborted. All statements issued inside that transaction will fail until a commit or rollback statement is executed to close that transaction.

```
ALTER SESSION SET TRANSACTION_ABORT_ON_ERROR = TRUE;
```